# Can't run PHP SOAP (looking for help or alternative)

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm running CentOS 5.9 on this MediaTemple server with PHP 5.3.5, and I need to install SOAP for an API I'm building.

The phpinfo() output lists --enable-soap=shared already, so right off the bat I'm confused.

`yum install php-soap` doesn't work; it complains about "php-common = 5.1.6-43.el5_10" missing, yet `yum install php-common` says that `php-common-5.1.6-43.el5_10.x86_64` is already installed.

I ended up just installing it manually like so:

```
wget ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/5.10/updates/x86_64/RPMS/php-soap-5.1.6-43.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh --nodeps php-soap-5.1.6-43.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
```

And while it installed, I now get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so: undefined symbol: zend_unmangle_property_name_ex in Unknown on line 0
```

I imagine there are some dependency issues but I can't figure out how to solve them.

At this rate I'm resorting to just using a non-plugin form of SOAP solution.

Comment: Have you looked at PHP 5+ SoapClient [link] (http://us1.php.net/SoapClient).  You may be able to do your server interaction through that class.  Also, I believe SOAP was pre install/configured on most distro since 5+.  As alternative to SOAP, you might consider JQuery and AJAX as another means to process data in the background.

Comment: That's my exact problem; I don't have php-soap loaded so I can't use SoapClient; it throws class not found.

Comment: As a side note, once you have installed SOAP, you'll need to re configure PHP with SOAP. The '--enable-soap' would be added to your other configurations.  from command line, try php -i to get all the current options PHP was configured with.

Comment: Forgot to mention (adding to main question shortly); The phpinfo() output lists --enable-soap=shared already, before I touched anything.

Comment: I checked my install on CentOS 6 and I have the same also, under the SOAP description check to make sure you see the following: soap

Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled

Comment: Nope; nothing. Besides, there's still the matter of SOAP.so not even loading.